# C++ альтернатива bitset

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, мне недавно понадобилось для уменьшения "веса" булевого массива применять цепочку битов, для этого использовал `vector<bool>`, работало очень медленно, `bitset`, оказался быстрее, но не настолько, насколько хотелось бы.

Собственно вопрос.

1. Имеется ли более быстрая альтернатива bitset?
2. И можно ли делать двумерный bitset?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из bitset вполне можно сделать матрицу:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
class BitMatrix {
    private:
        typedef std::bitset<M * N> Data;

    public:
        bool operator() (size_t m, size_t n) const
        {
            return data_[m * N + n];
        }

        typename Data::reference operator() (size_t m, size_t n)
        {
            return data_[m * N + n];
        }

    private:
        std::bitset<M * N> data_;
};

// ... 
BitMatrix<10, 20> m;
m(1,1) = true;
m(2,2) = false;
std::cout << m(1,1) << m(2,2) << "\n";
```

Comment: Зачем нужны такие сложности, когда можно сделать массив bitset'ов с обычной [] индексацией?

    std::bitset<64> bits[32];
    bits[5][49]=true;

Comment: Может из-за чуть более экономного расхода памяти, в целом с массивом действительно проще.

Answer (score 4):

Операции с битами вообще не слишком быстрые.

Надо извлечь байт (или лучше long), содержащий заданный бит, сделать сдвигом нужную маску, возможно инвертировать ее (для сброса бита), протестировать или изменить и записать байт обратно.

Возможно Вам следует сделать это самому (видимо без вызова функций (или попробуйте static inline функции)), может быть удасться ускорить алгоритм если у Вас есть какие-то специфические (по логике задачи) зависимости между группами битов. Например иногда можно сильно повысить производительность, проверяя байт (или слово) на ноль и не тестировать там индивидуальные биты.

Comment: Ясно, ответьте пожалуйста на 2 пункт, может существуют уже готовые заголовки/библиотеки для двумерного bitset?

Comment: Кстати, для ускорения можно заранее посчитать нужные битовые маски, а потом их только применять.

Comment: По поводу 2, обычный массив long можно считать двумерным битовым массивом 32*n бит. А вообще все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: И как это сделать?

Comment: Задача:составить битовый массив (матрица смежности графа)

Comment: По поводу задачи: если узлов мало, а связей много, то проще использовать двумерный массив bool. А если наоборот, узлов много, а связей мало, то выгоднее использовать не матрицу смежности, а список ребер. Если узлов порядка миллиона, то никакая плотная упаковка битов не поможет.

Comment: P.S. как вариант, можно попробовать сделать что-то вроде разрежённого массива (sparse array). Физически это будет список ребер, а доступ будет как к матрице смежности.

Answer (score 4):

> Имеется ли более быстрая альтернатива bitset?

Нет. Если бы можно было сделать быстрее, bitset, я думаю, сделали бы быстрее. У бита нет отдельного адреса, чтобы обратиться к конкретному биту, нужно обратиться к байту, в котором он находится, и определить его при помощи сдвига и маски. Если у тебя в работе с битами слабое место, попробуй реализовать её самостоятельно, возможно, даже на ассемблере.

> И можно ли делать двумерный bitset?

А в чём проблема? Делаешь массив bitset и всё.

Comment: Учитывая что вопрос был в 2012 году, у меня есть сомнения насчёт того, стал бы компилятор инлайнить и заменять присваивания битов через ссылки на битовые операции (особенно, если этим компилятором являлся VS2010) - в таком случае свой вариант может работать намного быстрее.